# While Installing STS in Eclipse IDE for Java Developers showing error

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

Im setting up a STS into my eclipse for creating spring boot project. But while install sts from market place it showing error.

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Spring IDE AJDT Integration (optional) 3.9.9.201906180643-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.ajdt.feature.feature.group 3.9.9.201906180643-RELEASE)
  Missing requirement: Spring IDE Live Beans Graph 3.9.9.201906180643-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.livegraph 3.9.9.201906180643-RELEASE) requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.zest.core [1.0.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Spring IDE AJDT Integration (optional) 3.9.9.201906180643-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.ajdt.feature.feature.group 3.9.9.201906180643-RELEASE)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.springframework.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Spring IDE Core (required) 3.9.9.201906180643-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 3.9.9.201906180643-RELEASE)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.livegraph [3.9.9.201906180643-RELEASE,3.9.9.201906180643-RELEASE]
```

**[Spring Tools 3 (Standalone Edition) 3.9.9 Release](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-3-standalone-edition)**

Comment: Any reason why you still use STS3 instead of 4 ?

Comment: even i tried with 4 but same issue.

Comment: This Marketplace item has different update URLs for different Eclipse version. Does [upgrading to Eclipse 2019-06](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades) before installing STS 3 fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The installation process seems to complain about a missing bundle `org.eclipse.zest.core`. This bundle comes from the main Eclipse p2 repository and is not part of the STS 3.9.9 p2 repo. During the install of the Marketplace entry, all the configured p2 repos are being taken into account, so that selecting the STS 3.9.9 entry from the marketplace will cause this bundle to be downloaded from the main Eclipse p2 repo.

Therefore, please make sure that the main Eclipse p2 repo is configured in your preferences (`Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Update Sites`) and enabled.

In case it is, there might be stale cache data around that prevents Eclipse from finding that bundle in the main Eclipse repo. In that case, remove the main Eclipse p2 repo from the preferences, restart Eclipse, and add it back. Then try the marketplace entry for STS 3.9.9 again.